# Disable TLS 1.3 for GRPC or system-wide in Ubuntu?

Tags: ssl, openssl, grpc, tls1.2, boringssl

I'm trying to use a GRPC client which is TLS 1.3 enabled on my system (Ubuntu 20.04). I'd like to force it to connect over TLS 1.2: I don't see any options to control this, so I thought I'd try disabling TLS 1.3 system-wide.

How do I do this? I tried adding

```
MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

to my `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` as [this page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CONF_cmd.html) seems to suggest*, but my GRPC traffic continues over TLS 1.3 (perhaps I'm not reloading  the config or something?). I've heard mention of `boringssl` when it comes to GRPC as well, so perhaps that has something to do with things.

- I added it as the second line, right after `HOME = .`: you can see the whole file [here](https://gist.github.com/anlsh/bbf67501e5561fc95fe03cd24853a86c)